# Unable to deploy n1-standard instances to nane-1a zone + Your free trial credit will be used for this VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am having issues creating an n1-standard instance in northamerica-northeast1-a. The error is: "A n1-standard-1 VM instance is currently unavailable in the northamerica-northeast1-a zone." I know this is not true because I can deploy in this zone at work which is a sub-billing account. It's just not working in my individual/personal account. I am wondering if there is a problem with my account?
I have passed my free trial a long time ago and this message is still being displayed after upgrading to a paid account: Your free trial credit will be used for this VM instance.

Thanks,
Luc

I tried googling this issue and looked at all my billing account configurations.

Comment: Best to check with [GCP Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) once.

Comment: I am talking with support now to see what they say. Thanks.

Comment: That's a completely common and standard error. Free trial users have lower priority than paid users. It even happens to paid accounts at times depending on availability in a region. Change regions or change VM types. Also this is likely better answered on serverfault.com than on stackoverflow.com as it's about server resources, not programming. Check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info as I suspect this question will be closed.

Comment: ok, thanks! Sorry for the unnecessary post.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from support:

Thank you for holding. To best assist with this matter, I have reached out to our internal downstream team and we've confirmed that the error message received is related to resource stock out in the requested region. I understand that you're able to make use/deploy the same resources but on a different billing account (sub account). At times, the error message is triggered due to different constraints on each account. Therefore, the resource will be most likely available on a business account rather than an Individual/Personal account.

We currently suggest that you attempt to deploy the workload in a different region or try again later